# Dynamic Compression and RouteCollections (Rewritten URLs)

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression, routes

When a page is served, i.e., http://some.tld/FAQ.aspx, dynamic compression works just fine; The aspx extension is registered as a file type to compress.

But when using `routes.MapPageRoute` to rewrite the url as some.tld/FAQ IIS will not compress this page. There's no extension to register here.

Does anyone know how to get IIS to compress pages when using RouteCollections?